# Cannot replace String portion based on Array in Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have two arrays, one is for a case and other one for b case. I want bodyTags string which consist one or more of different arr1 items to be replaced with items from arr2 with the same index.

Code below doesn't work. If you can fix it or advice me how to achieve desired effect with jQuery this will really help me out.

```
var arr1 = ["1a", "2a", "3a", "4a", "5a", "a6", "7a", "8a", "9a"];
var arr2 = ["1b", "2b", "3b", "4b", "5b", "6b", "7b", "8b", "9b"];

    var bodyTags = 'something a1 got funcky a6';

    for (var i = 0; i < arr1.length; i++) {
        bodyTags = bodyTags.replace(/arr1[i]/gi, arr2[i]);
    }
```

Comment: Did you notice you're letters are reversed in the bodyTags string? "a1" instead of "1a".

Comment: no but it doesn't matter because these are fake values to avoid irrelevant information

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the regular expression, `arr1[i]` will be taken literally. If you want to have dynamic expressions, you have to use [**`RegExp`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/regexp):

```
bodyTags.replace(new RegExp(arr1[i],'gi'), arr2[i]);
```

Comment: Ok, thanks just one small question if values in arr1 made of signs like )(<> and other similar stuff, how can i escape all of those in once without changing arr1 items

Comment: function regexEscape(text) {
    return text.replace(/[-[\]{}()*+?.,\\^$|#\s]/g, "\\$&");
} did the job, found there.... thank you so much

Answer (score 1):

May be this one?

```
for (var i = 0; i < arr1.length; i++) {
    myregexp = new RegExp(arr1[i], "gi");
    bodyTags = bodyTags.replace(myregexp, arr2[i]);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe this is what you need

```
var arr1 = ["1a", "2a", "3a", "4a", "5a", "a6", "7a", "8a", "9a"];
var arr2 = ["1b", "2b", "3b", "4b", "5b", "6b", "7b", "8b", "9b"];

var bodyTags = 'something 1a got funcky a6';

for (var i = 0; i < arr1.length; i++) {
    var re = new RegExp(arr1[i],"gi");
    bodyTags = bodyTags.replace(re, arr2[i]);
}
```

2 things:

1. bodyTags contains a1 that is not in the first array
2. The problem was that /arr1[1]/ is not looking for the value of arr[1] and concatenating it to the regexp its only hardcoding arr1[i] meaning that the regexp will match strings like 'arr1'